# Transform JSON object array for using select2 option group more simple

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-select2

I want to use select2 plugin with using templateResult and has option group in it, in the documentation it say we should following pattern array of object in order to make it work. I'm already make the pattern like should be given and the pattern result is like i want, but in order to transform into final result i'm took a lot of steps. How to make it more simple, so far in this code are fine but i feel to many step on it in order to transform into like what i want.

Note: x variable is result from database.

```js
let x = [
    {id_cp: 1, nama: 'Bank BJB', jenis: 'TB', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bjb.png'},
    {id_cp: 2, nama: 'Bank BJB Giro Payment', jenis: 'GI', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bjb.png'},
    {id_cp: 3, nama: 'CR Kantor Pusat', jenis: 'TN', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/tunai.png'},
    {id_cp: 4, nama: 'Bank BSI', jenis: 'TB', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bsi.png'},
    {id_cp: 5, nama: 'Bank BRI', jenis: 'TB', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bri.png'},
    {id_cp: 6, nama: 'Dana', jenis: 'EW', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/dana.png'},
    {id_cp: 7, nama: 'GoPay', jenis: 'EW', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/gopay.png'},
    {id_cp: 8, nama: 'Bank BRI', jenis: 'QR', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/qris.png'}
];

function selectLabel(arr) {
    arr = arr.map(function (elments) {
        return {
            id: elments.id_cp,
            text: elments.nama,
            jenis: elments.jenis,
            path_gambar: elments.path_gambar
        };
    });

    const outputGrouped = Object.values(arr.reduce((accu, {jenis, ...rest}) => {
        if(!accu[jenis]) {
            accu[jenis] = {jenis, children: []};
        }
        accu[jenis].children.push(rest);
        return accu;
    }, {}));
    
    // console.log(outputGrouped);
    
    const transformed = outputGrouped.map(({ jenis, children }) => ({
        text: jenis,
        children: children
    }));
    // console.log(transformed);

    return transformed;
}

console.log(selectLabel(x));
```

So how to transform data from x variable more simple from that code with the same result, because i took 3 step of block code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do renaming in a direct step.

```js
let x = [
    {id_cp: 1, nama: 'Bank BJB', jenis: 'TB', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bjb.png'},
    {id_cp: 2, nama: 'Bank BJB Giro Payment', jenis: 'GI', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bjb.png'},
    {id_cp: 3, nama: 'CR Kantor Pusat', jenis: 'TN', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/tunai.png'},
    {id_cp: 4, nama: 'Bank BSI', jenis: 'TB', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bsi.png'},
    {id_cp: 5, nama: 'Bank BRI', jenis: 'TB', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/bri.png'},
    {id_cp: 6, nama: 'Dana', jenis: 'EW', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/dana.png'},
    {id_cp: 7, nama: 'GoPay', jenis: 'EW', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/gopay.png'},
    {id_cp: 8, nama: 'Bank BRI', jenis: 'QR', path_gambar: '/assets/images/partners/qris.png'}
];

function selectLabel(array) {
    return Object.values(array.reduce((accu, { id_cp: id, jenis: text, nama, path_gambar }) => {
        (accu[text] ??= { text, children: [] }).children.push({ id, text: nama, path_gambar });
        return accu;
    }, {}));
}

console.log(selectLabel(x));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But is seem the result of set that only get the first type of jenis key, the other with same jenis value are missing

Comment: There are missing other array value

Comment: Oh, i found the missing code from your answer that is when checking the value of jenis are same or not => if(!accu[text]) {
            accu[text] = { text, children: [] };
        }
 (accu[text]).children.push({ id, text: nama, path_gambar });

Comment: sorry some `??` was missing. please see edit.

Comment: Yes that the missing one, and now the result are great.